# How do I qualify for employment as an IT project manager?

Tags: management, recruitment, hiring-process, it

Currently i am a developer with around 6 years of development experience in various stacks.
I have a masters degree in computer science and have worked in several scrum teams, partially as scrum master. I know about agile processes by practice. In the next days, i  would like to switch to another company.

I haven't got any formal management qualifications.

How do I qualify for employment as an IT Project Manager (more technical, e.g. Product Owner) when applying for a position at a new company?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere between the two stages you mentioned, please insert a selection process / procedure for sake of completeness.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't qualified and need more experience. Strive for a team lead position, get a scrum master certification and serve in that role, etc. Before I became a software engineering manager, I worked up to a senior engineer, then lead engineer, etc. There is a progression. Six years of dev doesn't make a person ready to manage a team.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to evolve as a project manager, the best is to do so in your current company.
To get your manager to offer you more responsibility and eventually a job as project manager, there are a few options:

- show that you're ready to take on responsibility
- show that you're interested in your colleagues' work, not just your own
- show that the effort and duration components of a task are as important as the purely technical aspect of a task.

It will be probably much quicker to acquire your project management skills in a field you know (the one you're in now) than in a new company.

Personally, as a manager:

- I don't hire people (from the market) for a project manager job who don't have prior project management experience.
- I prefer instead to promote experienced engineers to project managers

Answer (score 0):

You have 6 years of experience as a developer. I am sure you have worked with project manager before, and know what their job requirements and functionalities are.

Right now, you have no work experience as an IT project manager, and want to apply for that position. Not many companies are willing to hire someone with no experience and pay them the salary of a worker of 6 years of experience.

So, you need some small companies that are willing to take a chance on you and give you some training so that you can work and gain some beginning experiences as a project manager first. Then, after at least 1 or 2 years, you can jump in and do big jobs as IT project managers.